# Providing alternate display text for links in messages from Einstein bots

Tags: html, einstein, einstein-bots

I'm just starting to learn Einstein bots in Salesforce, and I'm not the SF Administrator at our organization so I don't have a directly line to SF Support. Hoping someone here can help.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is change the appearance of links in messages sent by the Einstein bot from displaying as URLs, to displaying as specified clickable text, much as one would do inside of Word or many WYSIWYG HTML editors.

We have the HTML add-ons available here installed:

https://quip.com/WM7AA3tXRsaf

I thought that the unescaped HTML add-on would work for this, but I can't get it to display the way I want (it just writes the full HTML out instead of the URL).

Any thoughts? Perhaps that *is* the right add-on for markup, but I'm entering in the syntax incorrectly? The syntax is  lwc:html:{htmlText}

I've tried entering (in the Message text field for the message)

`lwc:<a href="http://mylink">{linktext}`

But it doesn't seem to display.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb 2024, the enhanced bot does not support hyperlink as you pointed out, as well as rich text formatting. Those 2 features are basic which are in the standard bot.

I wonder why SF would not have those features in the enhanced bot.